# User enter the command programmatically in the cmd

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

I want to build a windows application that can prompt CMD. However I would like to enable user enter the command programmatically. As in my code below, I enable to called CMD but the command (e.g. ipconfig) is only hardcoded. I want user to enter other command.

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.Start();
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("ipconfig");
    process.StandardInput.Flush();
    process.StandardInput.Close();
    process.WaitForExit();

    string s = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    richTextBox1.Text = s;
}
```

Comment: So as I read your code, when the text in richTextBox1 changes you call ipconfig, the result of which you then assign to the text of richTextBox1 - doesn't that fire the TextChanged event again? Why are you using the TextChanged event anyway as it will fire for every change, i.e. every character that is typed? Why not have one textbox which contains the command and a "go" button which reads the value of the textbox and calls cmd with it, and then shows the result in richTextBox1 or a multi-line textbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this....

```
 // you can populate command from user input
 String command  = "ipconfig";
  // or
 command = userTxt.Text;
 process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command );
```